# Audio Play button is not showing in iMessage after sharing an Audio URL having meta Open Graph tags

Tags: html, ios, audio, facebook-opengraph, imessage

I have added below Open Graph Meta tags for playing audio in iMessage when an Audio URL will be shared. But I can't see the Audio Play button rest of the meta tags are working.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Guess I'm a bad liar" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Guess I'm a bad liar" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://lyritext.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://208.109.53.118/images/lyritext_logo_songclip.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="lyritext logo" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="http://208.109.53.118/images/lyritext_logo_songclip.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:audio" content="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3" />
<meta property="og:audio:secure_url" content="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3" />
<meta property="og:audio:type" content="audio/mpeg" />
```

Comment: I got this issue resolved. I just replaced the IP 208.109.53.118 with the domain name and the Audio play button started appearing in iMessage chat.